# Create React App with an older version of node

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, npm, create-react-app

I am trying to use **Create React App** but getting an error that it requires **Node 10** or higher. My node version is **Node 8.10.0** and there's no way for me to update the Node version since it's a work machine. Is there any way to run an older version of Create React App to work with my older Node version?

Comment: Node 8 support was removed in the `4.0.0` version. You could try to use the last `3.x.x` `create-react-app` version, seems like it's `3.4.1`.

Comment: Node 8 has not been maintained since the start of 2020. You really should tell your workplace to update to a maintained LTS version.

Comment: @AKX Will do, thanks!

Comment: @sergdenisov I'm still getting the same error with that version and even with 1.0.0

Answer (score 32, accepted):

I managed to run it. It seems like the last versions of the packages which support **Node 8.x.x** are **3.4.1** for `create-react-app` and **3.1.1** for `react-scripts`. What I did:

```
npm uninstall -g create-react-app
npm install -g create-react-app@3.4.1
create-react-app my-app --scripts-version 3.1.1
```

But it's better to update your Node version to the actual (or LTS at least).

Comment: Thanks so much, will be updating the Node version in the near future.

Comment: This will install react version 17 by default. If anyone wants to work with version 16, this solution will also work. You just have to npm install the react / react-dom version 16.

Comment: @JorgeMauricio do you know which command will install create react app with node 16? I need to downgrade from node 17.

Comment: @cheznead
You can try something like this:
npx create-react-app@3.4.1 <project-name> --scripts-version 3.1.1

Answer (score 2):

From my understanding you can add the flag `--scripts-version` to your `npx create-react-app` command. So for example if you wanted to run react version 15.6 you would run something like:

```sh
npx create-react-app appname --scripts-version 1.0.14
```

You can reference the [react-script repo](https://github.com/facebook/create-react-app/tree/master/packages/react-scripts) as well as the [NPM Package](https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-scripts) for more information on which version of the script you would want to run. Hopefully this helped! If not please let me know and I'm more than willing to try and look more into it.

*Edit:*

Forgot to mention that you need to make sure to change the versions of react and react dom within your package.json after. So after installing you would run:

```sh
npm i react@15.6
npm i react-dom@15.6
```

Comment: I'm running this command and still getting the same error with any scripts-version. `npx create-react-app appname --scripts-version 3.4.0 --template typescript`

Comment: Do you have any other suggestions? I really need this working

Comment: Sorry didn't see your response earlier. I'm glad to hear the other solution worked for you though. I guess installing the react version you want globally would make sense as a good solution.